# How to open a PDF file from Unix Putty Box( PGP)

Tags: pdf, pgp

I have a situation where i am unable to open the PDF files from the Unix Putty box.The vendor is placing these files in Server(We called it as Q drive) and we were ftp these from files from Q drive to Unix server(PGP box).
The problem is when we ftp these files to unix server and then downloading them to our desktop from the Unix box we were unable to open them.
These files are getting opened when we directly download them from Q drive to our desktops.  Do we need to install any tools to open them?
We tried copying these files to desktop from Putty box but still unable to open them.
Is there anything we need to do to make these files open?

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask your vendor...

Comment: When you FTP the files over, do you use binary or text transfer? It should be binary.

Comment: What is Unix Putty box ? on Google it gives only five results with this exact term.

Comment: @Kiwy I imagine the “Unix Putty box” is the system they connect to using SSH (and PuTTY), and the “PGP box” is another system which performs encryption/decryption/signing operations...

Comment: This is far too vague and nonsensical to be of use to the world at large in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by switching FTP to binary mode before transferring the PDF files.

Some (most?) FTP clients will default to text transfer which involves converting the data to "8-bit ASCII" before transferring the files.  This may corrupt files that are not plain text ASCII files (PDF files are generally not plain text files).